# R list parts of a function

Tags: r, function

I have a large function I use to assign variable types to columns in a data frame.

```
setVarType <- function(x){
    x$Species <- as.factor(as.character(x$Species))
    x$Sepal.Length <- as.numeric(as.character(x$Sepal.Length))
    return(x)
}

df1 <- setVarType(df1)
```

I just created a new version of the data frame and the function is breaking because some of the column names are missing in the new data set.  Is there a way to see the structure of a function and extract the required variable names into a vector so I can do something like:

```
setdiff(functionVariables, dataFrameVariables)
```

Comment: It strikes me as if you’re trying to solve the wrong problem here. Why is your function not parametrised on the names of the columns? This shouldn’t be hard-coded if it’s something variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
getLValueDollarRHS <- function(pt) do.call(c,lapply(as.list(pt),function(pte) if (is.call(pte)) c(if (pte[[1]] == '<-' && is.call(pte[[2]]) && pte[[2]][[1]] == '$') as.character(pte[[2]][[3]]),getLValueDollarRHS(pte))));
getLValueDollarRHS(body(setVarType));
## [1] "Species"      "Sepal.Length"
```

Demo on a built-in function:

```
getLValueDollarRHS(body(xtabs));
## [1] "data"               "..."                "exclude"            "drop.unused.levels" "sparse"
```